# How to limit a function to some of the parameters?

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() {
 foo(() {});
 foo((_) {});
}

void foo(Function callback) => null;
```

How can I limit `callback` to only have either `VoidCallback` or `ValueChanged`. Currently, it accepts all types of `Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot limit `callback` to `VoidCallback` or to `ValueChanged` at compilation time.  You could use runtime checks:

```dart
void foo(Function callback) {
  if (callback is! VoidCallback && callback is! ValueChanged) {
    throw ArgumentError(
        'Only VoidCallback and ValueChanged callbacks are allowed');
  }
  // ...
}
```

However, I don't recommend that since it makes your API harder to use.  As an example, see [`Future.catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) which similarly tries to accept multiple callback types and checks them at runtime.  Unfortunately, it:

- Reduces self-documentability of the code, and documentation can be awkward. (For the case of `Future`, the error callback documentation is confusingly in [`Future.then`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/then.html).)
- Trades static type checks for runtime checks, which makes mistakes harder to catch.

In your case, IMO it would be simpler to always take a `ValueChanged` callback, and callers can trivially ignore the argument if it's not needed:

```dart
void main() {
 foo((_) {});
 foo((_) => someVoidCallback());
}

void foo<T>(ValueChanged<T> callback) => null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. What would you even do with such a datatype?

In other languages, you would use method overloading and have two methods, one for each type. Dart does not support that, see [Why does dart not allow method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626833/why-does-dart-not-allow-method-overloading)

You can have two differently named methods though.

If you have some value with your callback that a `ValueChanged` method can make use of, then use that datatype. A consumer having only a `VoidCallback` will have to ignore the parameter, just as you did in your code.

Comment: "What would you even do with such a datatype?" -- I'm not looking for a datatype, I thought I could do some kind of overloading or create such `typedef`. Thanks for your answer.